# htaccess rules efficent way?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i have a bunch of ReWrite rules up in my .htaccess file.
The reason behind this is to have my server handle the file arabic.php behind
the scenes when an end user browse to www.mysite.co.uk/عربية :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^عربية$ arabic.php
```

i have about 40 rules like the one mentioned above. Is this "Okay" with apache or am i pushing it and there's a better way to achieve my end goal?

Comment: examples: RewriteRule ^عربية$ arabic.php
RewriteRule ^الأغاني$ songs.php RewriteRule ^الفنان$ artist.php and so on.. so there isn't any particular rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s fine like having any other 40 rules as it’s only string comparison using regular expressions.

But you need to use a proper character encoding, at best UTF-8 as that’s the preferred character encoding for non-ASCII characters. In your case the path `/عربية` might actually be encoded as `/%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9` that is percent-encoded form of the text `عربية` when encoded in UTF-8.

But there also might be cases where the browser does not use UTF-8 but a different encoding. Either because the browser uses a different character encoding for the URL or because someone followed a link on a web page that uses a different character encoding other than UTF-8 and did not use proper percent-encoding like when used in plain:

```
<a href="http://example.com/عربية">
```

In that case `عربية` is encoded with the same character encoding as the document uses.