# 600 + mode rewrite rules, is that okay with apache?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are building a website that hopefully will serve 2k-5k uniques per day.
Because the website is oriented for arab speakers we configured the .htaccess
file to make rewrite rules like:

```
RewriteRule ^عربية$ arabic.php [L]
```

Problem is we have 600 Rewrite Rules like the one above.
Is this Okay with apache? or is this going to make my server real slow?
does the [L] tag help?

Comment: Keep in mind that apache needs to parse .htaccess at every request. You should move the rewrite rules to your VirtualHost config (usually in httpd.conf), which only gets parsed once: when apache is starting.

Comment: What about [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302133/htaccess-rules-efficent-way)?

Comment: @Gumbo it scaled from 40 to 600 :)

Comment: @Maerlyn that would be great, so if i do that i won't have any performance issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have just static keywords, I would rather use a [hash map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) instead of separate rules. Because the complexity of the find operation for a hash map is O(1) in opposite to O(*n*) for *n* rules.

So you could do something like this:

```
RewriteMap arabic-keywords dbm:/path/to/file/arabic-keywords.map
```

The initial keywords map is a plain text file of the format:

```
عربية arabic.php
الأغاني songs.php
الفنان artist.php
```

Then use [`httxt2dbm`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httxt2dbm.html) to turn the plain text file into a hash map:

```
httxt2dbm -i arabic-keywords.txt -o arabic-keywords.map
```

And the use of the map:

```
RewriteCond %{arabic-keywords:$0} .+
RewriteRule .+ %0 [L]
```

As a hash rewrite map returns an empty string if no match was found, the condition will only be fulfilled if a match was found. But note that `RewriteMap` cannot be used in the .htaccess file [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context).

Comment: you already know my problem quit well now, i need to choose the has map or the httpd.conf way. what is your final take? :)

Comment: @Tom: I wouldn’t propose the hash map if it wouldn’t be the optimum.

Comment: +1 For using RewriteMap in this case. You could even rewrite them based on a script if you want instead of using a static file, just check the apache docs :p.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is too much for performance and for maintainability.

I would make one rewrite rule to forward everything related requests to arabic.php, then process the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] with php for more dynamic routing.

This would be more maintainable.

Comment: That's how wikipedia does it's magic, but our website isn't that scalable but thanks for your 2 cents friend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing maintenance on a website with similar vistor rates and it has currently around 500 mod rewrite rules. They have little impact on the overal performance.

The `[L]` tag does help a bit in this performance. Especially if you keep your most used rules on the top of the page.

Comment: nice to hear that from someone who has the same issue. @pinusngra says otherwise, can someone add another opinion?

Comment: Well, I agree with @pinusnegra that something more efficient could be achieved. Just pointing out that this doesn't have to be a major bottleneck.